# combining two data frames of different lengths

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames.
The first is of only one column and 10 rows.
The second is of 3 columns and 50 rows.

When I try to combine this by using `cbind`, it gives this error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :

Can anyone suggest another function to do this?
P.S I have tried this using lists too, but it gives the same error.

The data frame consisting of 3 columns should be the first 3 columns in a CSV file, whereas the data frame with one column should be the fourth column in that file, when I write with the `write.table` function. The first 3 columns have 50 rows and the fourth column should occupy the first 10 rows.

Comment: R is properly returning an error here.  Until you specify what you'd like done with the extra rows, it doesn't know what to do.

Comment: What behavior do you expect for the mismatched rows?

Comment: As @JD asks, what behavior do you expect?  Perhaps you're looking for a different behavior, like `merge()`.  Please clarify.

Comment: These are operations that Minitab and Excel would support. R is more structured.

Comment: This problem will be much more solvable if you explain the relationship between the two data.frames. Do the first 10 rows of the smaller correspond to the first 10 rows of the larger? Or some other set of rows? It sounds like `merge` by rowname is what you want here.

Comment: Hi all sorry for the confusion...the dataframe consisting of 3 columns should be first 3 columns in a csv file, where as the data frame with one column should be the fourth column in a csv file when i write write.table function. The first 3 columns has 50 rows and the fourth column should occupy first 10 rows

Comment: @alex, what behavior do you desire with the mismatches. In one of the comments below you say you don't want NAs. That's nice. But DO you want? Dropped?

Comment: Not sure what I'm not getting about SO but how come the answer with the most votes, a lot more than the other answers, doesn't actually answer the question? No offensive to Andrie...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill

Answer (score 38):

In the `plyr` package there is a function `rbind.fill` that will merge data.frames and introduce `NA` for empty cells:

```
library(plyr)
combined <- rbind.fill(mtcars[c("mpg", "wt")], mtcars[c("wt", "cyl")])
combined[25:40, ]

    mpg    wt cyl
25 19.2 3.845  NA
26 27.3 1.935  NA
27 26.0 2.140  NA
28 30.4 1.513  NA
29 15.8 3.170  NA
30 19.7 2.770  NA
31 15.0 3.570  NA
32 21.4 2.780  NA
33   NA 2.620   6
34   NA 2.875   6
35   NA 2.320   4
```

Comment: alex uses cbind rather than rbind.

Comment: @Max The way I see it, is that if you are trying to combine two data.frames with different `nrow` as well as `ncol` you wind up with the same problem, whether you `cbind` or `rbind`.  It just so happens that there is a potential existing solution using a variation of `rbind`.  This works in general, doesn't it?

Answer (score 23):

It's not clear to me at all what the OP is actually after, given the follow-up comments. It's possible they are actually looking for a way to write the data to file.

But let's assume that we're really after a way to `cbind` multiple data frames of differing lengths.

`cbind` will eventually call `data.frame`, whose help files says:

> Objects passed to data.frame should have the same number of rows, but
>   atomic vectors, factors and character vectors protected by I will be
>   recycled a whole number of times if necessary (including as from R
>   2.9.0, elements of list arguments).

so in the OP's actual example, there *shouldn't* be an error, as R ought to recycle the shorter vectors to be of length 50. Indeed, when I run the following:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- runif(50)
b <- 1:50
c <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],length.out = 50)
dat1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
dat2 <- data.frame(d = runif(10),e = runif(10))
cbind(dat1,dat2)
```

I get no errors and the shorter data frame is recycled as expected. However, when I run this:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- runif(50)
b <- 1:50
c <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],length.out = 50)
dat1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
dat2 <- data.frame(d = runif(9), e = runif(9))
cbind(dat1,dat2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 50, 9
```

But the wonderful thing about R is that you can make it do almost anything you want, even if you shouldn't. For example, here's a simple function that will `cbind` data frames of uneven length and automatically pad the shorter ones with `NA`s:

```
cbindPad <- function(...){
args <- list(...)
n <- sapply(args,nrow)
mx <- max(n)
pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
        nms <- colnames(x)
        padTemp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
        colnames(padTemp) <- nms
        if (ncol(x)==0) {
          return(padTemp)
        } else {
        return(rbind(x,padTemp))
          }
    }
    else{
        return(x)
    }
}
rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- runif(50)
b <- 1:50
c <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],length.out = 50)
dat1 <- data.frame(a,b,c)
dat2 <- data.frame(d = runif(10),e = runif(10))
dat3 <- data.frame(d = runif(9), e = runif(9))
cbindPad(dat1,dat2,dat3)
```

I make no guarantees that this function works in all cases; it is meant as an example only.

**EDIT**

If the primary goal is to create a csv or text file, all you need to do it alter the function to pad using `""` rather than `NA` and then do something like this:

```
dat <- cbindPad(dat1,dat2,dat3)
rs <- as.data.frame(apply(dat,1,function(x){paste(as.character(x),collapse=",")}))
```

and then use `write.table` on `rs`.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but is there anyway to just join the data frames without recycling itself or with NA values?

Comment: @alex - As I allude to in my answer, data frames are lists that are *specifically intended for the special case of equal rows*. Asking for a data frame with unequal rows is sort of nonsensical. What you want is a list.

Comment: @Thank you...my primary purpose was to post a bunch of tables to a csv  and this helped me solve.

Comment: when you have list with different column header? then how to combine them

Answer (score 1):

Refering to Andrie's answer, suggesting to use `plyr::rbind.fill()`:
Combined with `t()` you have something like `cbind.fill()` (which is not part of `plyr`) that will construct your data frame with consideration of identical case numbers.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to get max of rows count of all data.frames and next append empty matrix to every data.frame if need. This method doesn't require additional packages, only base is used. Code looks following:

```
list.df <- list(data.frame(a = 1:10), data.frame(a = 1:5), data.frame(a = 1:3))

max.rows <- max(unlist(lapply(list.df, nrow), use.names = F))

list.df <- lapply(list.df, function(x) {
    na.count <- max.rows - nrow(x)
    if (na.count > 0L) {
        na.dm <- matrix(NA, na.count, ncol(x))
        colnames(na.dm) <- colnames(x)
        rbind(x, na.dm)
    } else {
        x
    }
})

do.call(cbind, list.df)

#     a  a  a
# 1   1  1  1
# 2   2  2  2
# 3   3  3  3
# 4   4  4 NA
# 5   5  5 NA
# 6   6 NA NA
# 7   7 NA NA
# 8   8 NA NA
# 9   9 NA NA
# 10 10 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you!

You can use `library(qpcR)` for combining two matrix with unequal size.

```
resultant_matrix <- qpcR:::cbind.na(matrix1, matrix2)
```

NOTE:- The resultant matrix will be of size of matrix2.

Comment: qpcR needs a capital R for the package to be recognised --> resultant_matrix <- qpcR:::cbind.na(matrix1, matrix2). In my trial it took the dimension of the first and bigger matrix. Also worked on dataframes.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qpcR/qpcR.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Just my 2 cents. This code combines two matrices or data.frames into one. If one data structure have lower number of rows then missing rows will be added with NA values.

```
combine.df <- function(x, y) {
    rows.x <- nrow(x)
    rows.y <- nrow(y)
    if (rows.x > rows.y) {
        diff <- rows.x - rows.y
        df.na <- matrix(NA, diff, ncol(y))
        colnames(df.na) <- colnames(y)
        cbind(x, rbind(y, df.na))
    } else {
        diff <- rows.y - rows.x
        df.na <- matrix(NA, diff, ncol(x))
        colnames(df.na) <- colnames(x)
        cbind(rbind(x, df.na), y)
    }
}

df1 <- data.frame(1:10, row.names = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(1:5, row.names = 10:14)
combine.df(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't actually get an error with this.

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(sample(letters,50, replace=T),runif(100)), nrow=50))
b <- sample(letters,10, replace=T)
c <- cbind(a,b)
```

I used letters incase joining all numerics had different functionality (which it didn't). Your  'first data frame', which is actually just a vector', is just repeated 5 times in that 4th column...

But all the comments from the gurus to the question are still relevant :)

Comment: Ya even I get the data frame with less (10) rows repeating till the 50 rows, but I am curious to know if there is any way to just append only the 10 rows of data frame to 50 rows without putting any NA values..thank you

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand your point now. And you're talking about making a csv. I think you want write.csv(..., na="") That way you won't have "NA" "NA" printed all through your csv file. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score -2):

I think I have come up with a quite shorter solution.. Hope it helps someone.

```
cbind.na<-function(df1, df2){

  #Collect all unique rownames
  total.rownames<-union(x = rownames(x = df1),y = rownames(x=df2))

  #Create a new dataframe with rownames
  df<-data.frame(row.names = total.rownames)

  #Get absent rownames for both of the dataframe
  absent.names.1<-setdiff(x = rownames(df1),y = rownames(df))
  absent.names.2<-setdiff(x = rownames(df2),y = rownames(df))

  #Fill absents with NAs
  df1.fixed<-data.frame(row.names = absent.names.1,matrix(data = NA,nrow = length(absent.names.1),ncol=ncol(df1)))
  colnames(df1.fixed)<-colnames(df1)
  df1<-rbind(df1,df1.fixed)

  df2.fixed<-data.frame(row.names = absent.names.2,matrix(data = NA,nrow = length(absent.names.2),ncol=ncol(df2)))
  colnames(df2.fixed)<-colnames(df2)
  df2<-rbind(df2,df2.fixed)

  #Finally cbind into new dataframe
  df<-cbind(df,df1[rownames(df),],df2[rownames(df),])
  return(df)

}
```

Answer (score -3):

i had similar problem, i matched the entries in a particular column of two data sets and cbind only if it matched. 
For two data sets, data1 & data2, i am adding a column in data1 from data2 after comparing first column of both.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data1){
  for( j in 1:nrow(data2){
    if (data1[i,1]==data2[j,1]) data1[i,3]<- data2[j,2]
  }
}
```