# How do I stack data in R?

Tags: r, merge, dataset

I have 20 different .csv files and I need to some how stack the data in R so that I can get an overall picture of the data.
Presently I am copying and pasting the columns in excel to make one big data set.
However, I am sure there is a quicker and more efficient way of doing this in R as this would ultimately take a while.

Also, to make things worse some of the variable names are not the same in each data set.
eg VARIABLE1 is written as variable1 in some datasets. How would i rectify this in R as I understand that R is case sensitive?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and the fastest way to do this, if you're (or wish you to be) familiar with `data.table` package is this way (not tested):

```
require(data.table)
in_pth <- "path_to_csv_files" # directory where CSV files are located, not the files.
files <- list.files(in_pth, full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE, pattern="\\.csv$")
out <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread))
```

#### `list.files` parameters:

- `full.names = TRUE` will return the full path to your file. Suppose your `in_pth <- "c:\\my_csv_folder"` and inside this you've two files: `01.csv and 02.csv`. Then, `full.names=TRUE` will return `c:\\my_csv_folder\\01.csv` and `c:\\my_csv_folder\\02.csv` (**full path**).
- `recursive = FALSE` will not search inside **directories** within your `in_pth` folder. Assume you've two more csv files in `c:\\my_csv_folder\\another_folder`. Now, if you want to load these files inside this one, then you can set `recursive=TRUE`, which'll scan for files until you reach all directories searching down.
- `pattern=\\.csv$`: This is a regular expression to tell which sort of files to load. If your folder, in addition to csv files also has text files (.txt), then by specifying this pattern, you'll load only the `csv` files. If your folder has only CSV files, then this is not necessary.

---

#### data.table functions:

- `rbindlist` avoids conflict in column names by retaining the name of the previous data.table. That is, if you've two `data.table`s `dt1, dt2` with column names `x,y` and `a,b` respectively, then doing `rbindlist(dt1,dt2)` will take care of changing `a,b` to `x,y` and `rbindlist(dt2, dt1)` will take care of changing `x,y` to `a,b`.
- `fread` takes care of columns, headers separators etc most often automatically.. and is extremely fast (although still experimental, so you may want to check your output to be sure it's all fine (even if stable)).

Comment: Thanks! By "path_to_csv_files" its like "C:\MyFile.CSV"? Thus, where the .csv files are located? Also, can you explain the parameters of list.file? Apologies but I am relatively new to R.

Comment: Apologies again but when I type in require(data.table) it says there is no package called 'data.table'? Do I have to download this package somewhere or what?

Comment: `install.packages("data.table")`

Comment: Apologies again Arun, but when I try and run this it says that "Error could not find function 'rbindlist'"? Should it not be already installed as part of the package? Or is there any other function I could use in it's place~?

Comment: did you install `data.table` successfully? Then did you load the package by doing `require(data.table)`? Does it load successfully?

Answer (score 0):

@ Denis:It is also worth looking into the `plyr` package for the same. `rbind.fill(...)`  allows you to combine data.frames by row.

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
```

`help (rbind.fill)` for details gives you following:

`rbinds` a list of data frames filling missing columns with NA.

Usage

`rbind.fill(...)`
Arguments

... 
input data frames to row bind together. The first argument can be a list of data frames, in which case all other arguments are ignored.

Details

This is an enhancement to `rbind` that adds in columns that are not present in all inputs, accepts a list of data frames, and operates substantially faster.

Column names and types in the output will appear in the order in which they were encountered. No checking is performed to ensure that each column is of consistent type in the inputs.

To my knowledge,there is no `cbind.fill`; however, there is the user function `cbind.fill` that allows you to combine data.frames by column. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill).

There are two solutions:  one depending on `rbind.fill` in the `plyr package` and another is independent of `rbind.fill`.

Answer (score -1):

Another way, without using external packages, is to use the cbind() command: it makes the binding per column.. So if you have to different tables you can just pass them as arguments to cbind() and they will be appended

Comment: It'd be nice if you could post the answer (instead of just the how to:).