# Convert a list of varying lengths into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to convert a simple list of varying lengths into a data frame as shown below. I would like to populate the missing values with NaN. I tried using ldply, rbind, as.data.frame() but I failed to get it into the format I want. Please help.

```
x=c(1,2)
y=c(1,2,3)
z=c(1,2,3,4)
a=list(x,y,z)

a
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Output should be:

```
x   y   z
1   1   1
2   2   2
NaN 3   3
NaN NaN 4
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7962267/324364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rbind.fill.matrix` from "plyr" gets you very close to what you're looking for:

```
> library(plyr)
> t(rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(a, t)))
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    1    1    1
2    2    2    2
3   NA    3    3
4   NA   NA    4
```

Comment: Thanks @Ananda. Is there anyway I can retain column headers and also get **dataframe** as opposed to a matrix

Comment: @oostopitre, sure. Make sure you're using a named `list`, then you can do `setNames(data.frame(t(rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(a, t)))), names(a))`

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot of code, so not as clean as Ananda's solution, but it's all base R:

```
maxl <- max(sapply(a,length))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(a,function(x) x[1:maxl]))
# out <- matrix(unlist(lapply(a,function(x) x[1:maxl])), nrow=maxl) #another way
out <- as.data.frame(out)
#names(out) <- names(a)
```

Result:

```
> out
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3 NA  3  3
4 NA NA  4
```

Note: names of the resulting df will depend on the names of your list (`a`), which doesn't currently have names.