# Create columns of varying length from rows in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

This probably has incredibly simple answer, but I've been working on this for hours and I still can't figure it out. All I want to do is take a data frame with two columns (BEFORE table) and alter it so that each unique value in the first column becomes the name of each new column and the second column values fill in below their respective column name (AFTER table).

BEFORE

```
ID  age
N1   7
N1   8
N2   5
N3   9
N3   4
N3   9
```

AFTER

```
N1   N2   N3
7    5    9
8    NA   4
NA   NA   9
```

I've tried the `melt()` and `cast()` functions in the package reshape2, but they don't seem to do what I want. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing unique IDs, which you can easily create with `ave`. Once you have those, you can use `reshape()` from base R or `dcast()` from "reshape2" to get what you are looking for:

```
mydf$ID2 <- ave(as.character(mydf$ID), mydf$ID, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar="ID2", timevar="ID")
#   ID2 age.N1 age.N2 age.N3
# 1   1      7      5      9
# 2   2      8     NA      4
# 6   3     NA     NA      9

library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, ID2 ~ ID, value.var="age")
#   ID2 N1 N2 N3
# 1   1  7  5  9
# 2   2  8 NA  4
# 3   3 NA NA  9
```

Comment: Bingo. Beat me to it while I was a tracking down the duplicate. Haven't you got enough `reshape` tag points already? ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail, nope. I need to hit silver or gold first :)

Answer (score 1):

`acast` will get you partially there:

Original data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("N1", 
    "N2", "N3"), class = "factor"), age = c(7L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 5L
    )), .Names = c("ID", "age"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))
> df
  ID age
1 N1   7
2 N1   8
3 N2   5
4 N3   9
5 N3   4
6 N3   5

df2 <- acast(df, age~ID)

> df2
  N1 N2 N3
4 NA NA  4
5 NA  5  5
7  7 NA NA
8  8 NA NA
9 NA NA  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cbind.fill` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7962286/817778), you can do:

```
do.call(cbind.fill, split(df$age, df$ID))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    7    5    9
#[2,]    8   NA    4
#[3,]   NA   NA    5
```