# Remove < 0 values & delete rows

Tags: r

**Edit, have added code below**

First, sorry, I can't think if a good reproducible example at the moment, but my question I think can be answered without it.

My data involves some line graphs taken from a manually operated testing machine.
Because it's manually operated we get variable start times and thus the data is not properly "overlapped" with one another.

This was solved previously by using the following code:

```
#import data
x <- read.csv("smoke.csv", head=T, sep=",")

#flag '0' values, remove all zero values
row_sub = apply(x, 1, function(row) all(row > 0))
y <- x[row_sub,]
```

This worked before because of the small sample size and relatively tight timings. With more samples I'm now getting some 'clipping' in the graphs:

[image: picture]

I'm no expert so excuse the explanation: 'row_sub' is a modified version of 'x' which only keeps rows in which ALL values are > 0

The problem with this is illustrated in the attached image [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCuhS.jpg).
We can see the first sample is okay because it probably took the longest to insert into the apparatus. But the operator got better throughout the test, reducing sample feeding times, leading to the extreme clipping seen in sample4.

I know I can easily do this manually by simply deleting the leading zero values for each sample, then clipping the tail end of all the data to make sure they all have equal data points. But I can't figure out how to do it in R.

**Edit**
Here is the data: http://pastebin.com/iEW4sH2a

```
# Check & load required packages 
if (require("grid") == FALSE) install.packages("grid")
if (require("ggplot2") == FALSE) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (require("gridExtra") == FALSE) install.packages("gridExtra")
if (require("flux") == FALSE) install.packages("flux")
if (require("matrixStats") == FALSE) install.packages("matrixStats")
if (require("mgcv") == FALSE) install.packages("mgcv")


# Set working directory, read datafile
setwd("C location here")
x <- read.csv("smoke.csv", head=T, sep=",")
# Remove 'time' column

# flag '0' values, remove zero values
row_sub = apply(x, 1, function(row) all(row > 0, na.rm=TRUE))
y <- x[row_sub,]
rownames(y) <- NULL

# create time axis with appropriate length & attach to df
time <- seq(0,120, by=0.2)
time <- time[0:nrow(y)]
z <- cbind(time, y)
z <- na.omit(z)

#graph parameters
y_max <- 5.0

a.means <- rowMeans(z[,2:5])
b.means <- rowMeans(z[,6:9])
c.means <- rowMeans(z[,10:13])
d.means <- rowMeans(z[,14:17])

all.data <- cbind(z, a.means, b.means, c.means, d.means)

# Multiple plot function
#
# ggplot objects can be passed in ..., or to plotlist (as a list of ggplot objects)
# - cols:   Number of columns in layout
# - layout: A matrix specifying the layout. If present, 'cols' is ignored.
#
# If the layout is something like matrix(c(1,2,3,3), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE),
# then plot 1 will go in the upper left, 2 will go in the upper right, and
# 3 will go all the way across the bottom.
#
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, file, cols=1, layout=NULL) {
    require(grid)

    # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
    plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

    numPlots = length(plots)

    # If layout is NULL, then use 'cols' to determine layout
    if (is.null(layout)) {
        # Make the panel
        # ncol: Number of columns of plots
        # nrow: Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols
        layout <- matrix(seq(1, cols * ceiling(numPlots/cols)),
                         ncol = cols, nrow = ceiling(numPlots/cols))
    }

    if (numPlots==1) {
        print(plots[[1]])

    } else {
        # Set up the page
        grid.newpage()
        pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow(layout), ncol(layout))))

        # Make each plot, in the correct location
        for (i in 1:numPlots) {
            # Get the i,j matrix positions of the regions that contain this subplot
            matchidx <- as.data.frame(which(layout == i, arr.ind = TRUE))

            print(plots[[i]], vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = matchidx$row,
                                            layout.pos.col = matchidx$col))
        }
    }
}

#calculate area under curve
a.auc <- round(auc(z$time, a.means),2)
b.auc <- round(auc(z$time, b.means),2)
c.auc <- round(auc(z$time, c.means),2)
d.auc <- round(auc(z$time, d.means),2)
# Prepare plots

a_graph <- ggplot(data=all.data, aes(time)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=a1), alpha=0.1, color="indianred") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=a2), alpha=0.1, color="indianred1") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=a3), alpha=0.1, color="indianred2") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=a4), alpha=0.1, color="indianred3") +
    geom_line(aes(y=a.means), size=1, color="indianred4") +
    ggtitle("145A: Standard") +
    geom_text(aes(75, 1.5, label = a.auc)) +
    scale_x_continuous("Time(s)", limits=c(0,120)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Smoke(%Opacity)", limits=c(0,y_max))

b_graph <- ggplot(data=all.data, aes(time)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=b1), alpha=0.1, color="chartreuse") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=b2), alpha=0.1, color="chartreuse1") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=b3), alpha=0.1, color="chartreuse2") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=b4), alpha=0.1, color="chartreuse3") +
    geom_line(aes(y=b.means), size=1, color="chartreuse4") +
    ggtitle("145B: +0.5%") +
    geom_text(aes(75, 1.5, label = b.auc)) +
    scale_x_continuous("Time(s)", limits=c(0,120)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Smoke(%Opacity)", limits=c(0,y_max))

c_graph <- ggplot(data=all.data, aes(time)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=c1), alpha=0.1, color="turquoise") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=c2), alpha=0.1, color="turquoise1") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=c3), alpha=0.1, color="turquoise2") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=c4), alpha=0.1, color="turquoise3") +
    geom_line(aes(y=c.means), size=1, color="turquoise4") +
    ggtitle("145C: +1.0%") +
    geom_text(aes(75, 1.5, label = c.auc)) +
    scale_x_continuous("Time(s)", limits=c(0,120)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Smoke(%Opacity)", limits=c(0,y_max))

d_graph <- ggplot(data=all.data, aes(time)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y=d1), alpha=0.1, color="indianred") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=d2), alpha=0.1, color="indianred1") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=d3), alpha=0.1, color="indianred2") + 
    geom_point(aes(y=d4), alpha=0.1, color="indianred3") +
    geom_line(aes(y=d.means), size=1, color="indianred4") +
    ggtitle("145A: Standard") +
    geom_text(aes(75, 1.5, label = d.auc)) +
    scale_x_continuous("Time(s)", limits=c(0,120)) +
    scale_y_continuous("Smoke(%Opacity)", limits=c(0,y_max))

sample_names <- as.data.frame(c("145A", "145B", "145C", "145D"))
sample_auc <- as.data.frame(c(a.auc, b.auc, c.auc, d.auc))
sample_all <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample_names,sample_auc))
colnames(sample_all) <- c("x","y")

multiplot(a_graph, b_graph, c_graph, d_graph, cols=2)
```

Comment: Add the na.rm=TRUE argument.

Comment: Thanks, where would I add that argument? I'm not finding an obvious place, and there are no NA's to begin with. So I need to flag all values < 0 to equal NA first right?

Comment: `row_sub = apply(x, 1, function(row) all(row > 0, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm getting the same problem. Each beginning row is removed if the condition x > 0 is not true for each and every column in that row. The same thing happens with na.omit(x): I  have 1 single column that has NA's that start at row 600, the rest start at 700, but because of that one column all values for every sample are deleted if they go beyond 600. I'm not sure how to avoid this.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without a more detailed description of the data format and what you're trying to acheive

Comment: Yes sorry, let me modify and attach some code

Comment: av1, let me clarify what I'm trying to achieve again, as I thought I had done it sufficiently above. The picture shows 4 graphs, the first graph is fine, but then they get progressively worse because data has been clipped due to the function mentioned. Instead of individually removing values < 0 from each and every cell, it behave in another way: it removes -complete rows- if it detects that any cell at all has a value less than 0. You can see how this causes problems in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure I understand the question but I think I understand it better.

From my understanding, the columns of your data other than *time* are shifted forward by varying amounts with small values you don't care about at the beginning.

If this is the case, what you can do is define a threshold small value `thresh` after which you want to consider the data as the start in each column and discard everything before that.

```
## Untested ##
x <- lapply(x, as.numeric)
thresh <- 0.01
## store all indices until thresh is exceeded
ind2Rm <- lapply(x, function(col) 1:which(col > thresh)[1])
for(j in 2:length(x)) { # don't loop over time which is 1st column
  x[[j]] <- x[[j]][-ind2Rm[[j]]] # remove these first values that don't exceed thresh
}
```

After this, you would need to combine the data to plot back into a data frame.  Since the list elements will likely be different lengths, you can combine them into a data frame by padding NA's at the end of each column.  See the [answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill) for one approach to do this.

Comment: av1 Thanks for taking the time on this. Looks like you understand the question well enough. Your output is actually the closest I've come to what I need. Thanks! I will need to study your answer a bit to completely understand. I have a question: I need to graph this, I believe I need a dataframe for that, and to get a dataframe I believe all rows need to be equal. Am I right in thinking the next step involves making this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
dt <- list(ax = x[c(1,grep("a", colnames(x)))], bx = x[c(1,grep("b", colnames(x)))], cx = x[c(1,grep("c", colnames(x)))], dx = x[c(1,grep("d", colnames(x)))])

z <- lapply(dt, function(k) {
    out <- k[apply(k[-1], 1, function(row) all(row > 0, na.rm=TRUE)),]
    out$time <- seq(from = 0, by = 0.2, length = nrow(out))
    out
    })

Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="time", all = TRUE), z)
```

Comment: If I look at the output given by "z", I see that, for example the first value of a3 = 0.351 when actually the first non-zero number = .016. Simiarly with b2 the first listed value is 1.59 when actually the first non-zero is equal to .053