# Add Columns to an empty data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, row

I have searched extensively but not found an answer to this question on Stack Overflow.

Lets say I have a data frame a.

I define:

```
a <- NULL
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

If I wanted to add a column to this data frame as so:

```
a$col1 <- c(1,2,3)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "a", value = c(1, 2, 3)) : 
    replacement has 3 rows, data has 0
```

Why is the row dimension fixed but the column is not?

How do I change the number of rows in a data frame?

If I do this (inputting the data into a list first and then converting to a df), it works fine:

```
a <- NULL
a$col1 <- c(1,2,3)
a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

Answer (score 12):

The row dimension is not fixed, but data.frames are stored as list of vectors that are constrained to have the same length. You cannot add `col1` to `a` because `col1` has three values (rows) and `a` has zero, thereby breaking the constraint.  R does not by default auto-vivify values when you attempt to extend the dimension of a data.frame by adding a column that is longer than the data.frame.  The reason that the second example works is that `col1` is the only vector in the data.frame so the data.frame is initialized with three rows.

If you want to automatically have the data.frame expand, you can use the following function:

```
cbind.all <- function (...) 
{
    nm <- list(...)
    nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
    n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow))
    do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function(x) rbind(x, matrix(, n - 
        nrow(x), ncol(x)))))
}
```

This will fill missing values with `NA`.  And you would use it like: `cbind.all( df, a )`

Comment: I guess this close to what I have been doing already. I thought there is a smarter solution than this. I do realize that I was using a vector as opposed to adding it to a dataframe. Also, I probably didn't describe what I meant well when I used the word fixed. The row dimension cannot be changed easily like the column dimension.

Comment: Also, it is the same answer as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill

Answer (score 3):

if you have an empty dataframe, called for example df, in my opinion another quite simple solution is the following:

```
df[1,]=NA  # ad a temporary new row of NA values
df[,'new_column'] = NA # adding new column, called for example 'new_column'
df = df[0,] # delete row with NAs
```

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this where I read in data from multiple files, grab the column I want, and store it in the dataframe. I check whether the dataframe has anything in it, and if it doesn't, create a new one rather than getting the error about mismatched number of rows:

```
readCounts = data.frame()

for(f in names(files)){
    d = read.table(files[f], header=T, as.is=T)
    d2 = round(data.frame(d$NumReads))
    colnames(d2) = f
    if(ncol(readCounts) == 0){
        readCounts = d2
        rownames(readCounts) = d$Name
    } else{
        readCounts = cbind(readCounts, d2)
    }
}
```