# How to add multiple empty columns to a data.frame with 0 rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I can add columns to data.frame:

```
x <- head(iris)
y <- x[1:nrow(x) > 7, ]
x[c('NewCol1', 'NewCol2')] <- rep(c('a', 'b'), each = nrow(x))
```

For a data.frame with 0 row, it does not work:

```
# > y
# [1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

y[c('NewCol1', 'NewCol2')] <- rep(c('a', 'b'), each = nrow(y))

# Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I found this, [Add Columns to an empty data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684072/add-columns-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-r), but it doesn't help much.

expected output:

```
# > y
# [1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species      NewCol1      NewCol2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: I don't see how `y` qualifies as being an empty data frame.  It has contents.  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry about  that. I edited the question.

Comment: @RonakShah . I want add 2 new columns to y.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes. I added expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following code which creates an empty data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Ints=integer(),
                 Characters=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

One way to add a new column to this empty data frame is to use `cbind()`:

```
df2 <- cbind(df, data.frame(Stuff=character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

> df2
[1] Ints       Characters Stuff     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Then just add your data as you normally would, e.g.

```
> df2[1,] <- c(1, "hello", "world")
> df2
  Ints Characters Stuff
1    1      hello world
```

As you mentioned, this might cause a casting problem in the `Ints` column.  Assigning each column by itself avoids this, e.g.

```
df2$Ints <- c(1:5)
df2$Stuff <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
```

Or, you could use something like `read.table` to bring in your data, and explicitly assign the classes that way.

Comment: This works. but `f2[1,] <- c(1, "hello", "world")` changed the Ints col to character!

Comment: Anyway, what I want to do next is rbind the data.frames generated by lapply(some are empty). This does matter.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `read.table` by setting `col.names` parameter

```
read.table(text = "",col.names =  c(names(y), c("New_Col1", "New_Col2")))

#Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Specie   New_Col1  New_Col2   
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

We can also set our desired class by using the `colClasses` parameter

```
read.table(text = "",col.names =  c(names(y), c("New_Col1", "New_Col2")), 
                colClasses = c(sapply(y, class), "character", "character"))
```

So in this case the two new variables will get `character` class.