# An error when trying to insert data into an empty data frame

Tags: r

I have three columns from three different files. I want to merge these three columns in a new data frame. To do that, I did the following:

```
  df1 <- read.csv("location of file1")
  df2 <- read.csv("location of file2")
  df3 <- read.csv("location of file3")
  dataset <- data.frame(B1_1=integer(), B1_2=integer(), B1_3=integer(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  dataset$B1_1 <- df1$Rate
  dataset$B1_2 <- df2$Price
  dataset$B1_3 <- df3$Code
```

The error that I get:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, B1_1, value = c(5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L,  : 
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 0
```

I checked that each of `df1$Rate`, `df2$Price`, and `df3$Code` has data, in other words, they are not empty. Also, I also checked the data type of these columns and all of the three columns of integer type.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This question already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684072/add-columns-to-an-empty-data-frame-in-r  Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to replace a column of a zero-row data frame with a positive number of values.

```
# an example data frame with 2 columns and 0 rows
dat <- data.frame(a = integer(), b = integer())

# a vector of values that should be added to column "a"
vec <- 1:3

# create a data frame with the correct number of rows and add the values to the column
dat[seq_along(vec), ]$a <- vec

#      a  b
# NA   1 NA
# NA.1 2 NA
# NA.2 3 NA
```