# Descriptive statistics on grouped and ungrouped observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have recently migrated to R from Stata. I am unsure how to perform compute descriptive statistics on grouped and ungrouped observations.

Here's my data:

```
dput(DF)
structure(list(Product_Name = c("iPhone", "iPhone", "iPhone", 
"iPhone", "iPhone", "iPhone", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P", 
"Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P"), Product_Type = c("New", 
"New", "Refurbished", "New", "New", "Refurbished", "Refurbished", 
"Refurbished", "Refurbished", "Refurbished", "Refurbished", "Refurbished"
), Year = c(2006, 2011, 2009, 2008, 2011, 2009, 2012, 2007, 2013, 
2015, 2009, 2010), Units = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 
200, 120, 125, 345, 340)), .Names = c("Product_Name", "Product_Type", 
"Year", "Units"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

My data has products sold by year and type. Each product could a refurbished product or a new product. Further, if it was sold before 2010, I would mark it as sold in "Time 1" otherwise I would mark it as sold in "Time 2".

Here's my code for this:

```
DF[DF$Year<2010,"Time"]<-"1"
DF[DF$Year>=2010,"Time"]<-"2"
```

Now, I want to generate descriptive statistics for these time periods.

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(Product_Name, Product_Type,Time) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Count = n(), 
                   Sum_Units = sum(Units,na.rm=TRUE), 
                   Avg_Units = mean(Units,na.rm = TRUE), 
                   Max_Units=max(Units,na.rm = TRUE))
```

If we run above code, we would get descriptive statistics by `Product_Name`, `Product_Type`, and `Time` (i.e. grouped descriptive statistics). However, this is not what I want. I want descriptive statistics with and without considering groupings with `Product_Type` and `Time`. Meaning, I would want to compute descriptive statistics assuming that products were sold in Time 1 OR Time 2 (i.e. all years) and irrespective of the type of product sold, while retaining some of the grouped information above.

**Expected output:**

```
dput(DFOut)
structure(list(Product_Name = c("iPhone", "Nexus 6P"), New_Units_Sum_Time1 = c(500, 
NA), Refurbished_Units_Sum_Time_1 = c(900, 545), Sum_Units_Time1 = c(1400, 
545), Sum_Units_Time2 = c(700, 1285), Sum_Units_Time_1_And_2 = c(2100, 
1830), Avg_Units_Time1 = c(350, 272.5), Avg_Units_Time2 = c(350, 
321.25), Avg_Units_Time_1_And_2 = c(350, 305), Max_Units_Time1 = c(600, 
345), Max_Units_Time2 = c(500, 700), Max_Units_Time_1_And_2 = c(600, 
700)), .Names = c("Product_Name", "New_Units_Sum_Time1", "Refurbished_Units_Sum_Time_1", 
"Sum_Units_Time1", "Sum_Units_Time2", "Sum_Units_Time_1_And_2", 
"Avg_Units_Time1", "Avg_Units_Time2", "Avg_Units_Time_1_And_2", 
"Max_Units_Time1", "Max_Units_Time2", "Max_Units_Time_1_And_2"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

In the output, you would see that I have some descriptive statistics:

a) based on the type of product and the period it was sold (e.g. `New_Units_Sum_Time1` i.e. `New` and `Time1`). Please note that in the output, I have only shown the combination of `New` and `Time1`. If you can guide me how to produce descriptive statistics for other combinations of `Refurbished` and `Time`, it would be awesome.

b) based on ignoring type of product but not ignoring the period sold (e.g. `Sum_Units_Time1` i.e. `Time1`)

c) based on ignoring both type of product and period it was sold (e.g. `Sum_Units_Time_1_And_2`).

Ditto for Avg and Mean.

How can I do this? I'd appreciate any help. I am really struggling on this.

---

Please note that I manually created DFOut using Excel. Although I triple checked it, there could be some manual errors--I will be more than happy to clarify them if there are questions. Thank you for your time.

---

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices datasets  stats     graphics  grid      tcltk     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tables_0.8              Hmisc_4.0-2             Formula_1.2-1           survival_2.40-1        
 [5] ResourceSelection_0.3-0 magrittr_1.5            stringr_1.1.0           bit64_0.9-5            
 [9] bit_1.1-12              tufterhandout_1.2.1     knitr_1.15.1            rmarkdown_1.3          
[13] tufte_0.2               corrplot_0.77           purrr_0.2.2             readr_1.0.0            
[17] tibble_1.2              tidyverse_1.1.1         cowplot_0.7.0           plotly_4.5.6           
[21] ggplot2_2.2.1           maps_3.1.1              directlabels_2015.12.16 tidyr_0.6.1            
[25] ggthemes_3.3.0          R2HTML_2.3.2            lubridate_1.6.0         xts_0.9-7              
[29] zoo_1.7-14              lattice_0.20-34         corrgram_1.10           hexbin_1.27.1          
[33] sm_2.2-5.4              compare_0.2-6           installr_0.18.0         psych_1.6.12           
[37] reshape2_1.4.2          readstata13_0.8.5       pastecs_1.3-18          boot_1.3-18            
[41] vcd_1.4-3               car_2.1-4               xlsxjars_0.6.1          rJava_0.9-8            
[45] debug_1.3.1             dplyr_0.5.0             foreign_0.8-67          gmodels_2.16.2         
[49] openxlsx_4.0.0          plyr_1.8.4             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] minqa_1.2.4         colorspace_1.3-2    class_7.3-14        modeltools_0.2-21   mclust_5.2.2       
 [6] rprojroot_1.2       htmlTable_1.9       base64enc_0.1-3     MatrixModels_0.4-1  flexmix_2.3-13     
[11] mvtnorm_1.0-5       xml2_1.1.1          codetools_0.2-15    splines_3.3.2       mnormt_1.5-5       
[16] robustbase_0.92-7   jsonlite_1.2        nloptr_1.0.4        pbkrtest_0.4-6      broom_0.4.1        
[21] cluster_2.0.5       kernlab_0.9-25      httr_1.2.1          backports_1.0.5     assertthat_0.1     
[26] Matrix_1.2-7.1      lazyeval_0.2.0      acepack_1.4.1       htmltools_0.3.5     quantreg_5.29      
[31] tools_3.3.2         gtable_0.2.0        Rcpp_0.12.9         trimcluster_0.1-2   gdata_2.17.0       
[36] nlme_3.1-128        iterators_1.0.8     fpc_2.1-10          lmtest_0.9-34       lme4_1.1-12        
[41] rvest_0.3.2         gtools_3.5.0        dendextend_1.4.0    DEoptimR_1.0-8      MASS_7.3-45        
[46] scales_0.4.1        TSP_1.1-4           hms_0.3             parallel_3.3.2      SparseM_1.74       
[51] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  gridExtra_2.2.1     rpart_4.1-10        latticeExtra_0.6-28 stringi_1.1.2      
[56] gclus_1.3.1         mvbutils_2.7.4.1    foreach_1.4.3       checkmate_1.8.2     seriation_1.2-1    
[61] caTools_1.17.1      prabclus_2.2-6      bitops_1.0-6        evaluate_0.10       htmlwidgets_0.8    
[66] R6_2.2.0            gplots_3.0.1        DBI_0.5-1           haven_1.0.0         whisker_0.3-2      
[71] mgcv_1.8-16         nnet_7.3-12         modelr_0.1.0        KernSmooth_2.23-15  viridis_0.3.4      
[76] readxl_0.1.1        data.table_1.10.0   forcats_0.2.0       digest_0.6.12       diptest_0.75-7     
[81] stats4_3.3.2        munsell_0.4.3       registry_0.3        viridisLite_0.1.3   quadprog_1.5-5
```

Comment: So basically you need different grouping variable each time...? A series of `group_by %>% ... %>% ungroup() ....%>%... group_by..` ?

Comment: @Sotos - Thanks again for your help, as always. Yes, the only clarification I would add is that there are multiple layers: descriptive statistics by a) grouped based on product name, time and type b) grouped based on product name, time c) grouped based on product name. Does that help?

Comment: Well, yes. That is exactly what I understood :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to automate this is to first create a vector (`ind`) with all possible combinations of your grouping variables. We then take those combinations and convert them to formula with `Units`. As each formula is saved in a list (`l1`), we iterate over that list and aggregate.

```
ind <- unlist(sapply(c(2,3), function(i) combn(c('Product_Name', 'Product_Type', 'Time'), 
                                                             i, paste, collapse = '+')))

l1 <- sapply(ind, function(i) as.formula(paste('Units ~ ', i)))

lapply(l1, function(i) aggregate(i, df, FUN = function(j) c(sum1 = sum(j), 
                                                            avg = mean(j), 
                                                            max_units = max(j))))

#which gives

#$`Product_Name+Product_Type`
#  Product_Name Product_Type Units.sum1 Units.avg Units.max_units
#1       iPhone          New       1200       300             500
#2       iPhone  Refurbished        900       450             600
#3     Nexus 6P  Refurbished       1830       305             700

#$`Product_Name+Time`
#  Product_Name Time Units.sum1 Units.avg Units.max_units
#1       iPhone    1    1400.00    350.00          600.00
#2     Nexus 6P    1     545.00    272.50          345.00
#3       iPhone    2     700.00    350.00          500.00
#4     Nexus 6P    2    1285.00    321.25          700.00

#$`Product_Type+Time`
#  Product_Type Time Units.sum1 Units.avg Units.max_units
#1          New    1     500.00    250.00          400.00
#2  Refurbished    1    1445.00    361.25          600.00
#3          New    2     700.00    350.00          500.00
#4  Refurbished    2    1285.00    321.25          700.00

#$`Product_Name+Product_Type+Time`
#  Product_Name Product_Type Time Units.sum1 Units.avg Units.max_units
#1       iPhone          New    1     500.00    250.00          400.00
#2       iPhone  Refurbished    1     900.00    450.00          600.00
#3     Nexus 6P  Refurbished    1     545.00    272.50          345.00
#4       iPhone          New    2     700.00    350.00          500.00
#5     Nexus 6P  Refurbished    2    1285.00    321.25          700.00
```

Comment: Thanks Sotos...I changed your `df` to `DF1`, and I get this error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Units' not found` . Here's traceback:`10.
eval(expr, envir, enclos) 9.eval(predvars, data, env) 8.model.frame.default(formula = i, data = DF1) 7.stats::model.frame(formula = i, data = DF1) 6.eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
5.eval(m, parent.frame()) 4.aggregate.formula(i, DF1, FUN = function(j) c(sum1 = sum(j),    avg = mean(j), max_units = max(j))) 3.aggregate(i, DF1, ..2.FUN(X[[i]], ...) 1.
lapply(l1, function(i) aggregate(i, DF1, ..

Comment: hmm...don't know. Weird. It works perfect here. Is everything you are using up to date?

Comment: I have added my packages. I hope something is not wrong with my R install.

Comment: Ok. Got it. `DF1` should be `DF` in my code. Nothing wrong with your code. My bad.

Comment: Final question: is there any way I can combine all the lists into one, similar to the output I have posted? As in, I have only two rows for each `Product Name`. Any idea? I am asking because I want to compare descriptive statistics from "Time 1", "Time 2" and "Time 1 + Time 2". I was thinking to do this comparison row-wise ,and for this, I need all the columns in one data.frame or list.

Comment: If you look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962267/cbind-a-df-with-an-empty-df-cbind-fill) you ll find some `cbind.fill` functions that you can use. i.e. `do.call(cbind.fill, lapply(l1, function(i) aggregate(i, df, FUN = function(j) c(sum1 = sum(j), avg = mean(j), max_units = max(j)))))`

Comment: To be honest, I am not so comfortable yet with R because I am still a beginner. Is there anyway, you could help me out by producing the same output as the sample output posted above? I did run the command you have posted, but it seems all the columns have been bound together by `cbind.fill`. There are many duplicate columns. So, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, I don't have time right now to be honest... but as soon as I can I will give it a look. Meanwhile, this could be a good exercise for you

Comment: Sure I will definitely try. However, it will take time because I am a beginner and not really familiar with vectorization in your code. However, I won't give up. I will come back as soon as I have something. In the meantime, if you find chance, I'd truly appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Quick question: I am trying to understand why you did `unlist` on top of `sapply` for one line and not so for the other. Reading from `sapply` vs. `vapply` vs. `lapply` article by joran, `sapply` should have returned a vector or matrix. Right? I am taking baby steps to understand your code. I'd appreciate your thoughts.