# Add vector as a column to a data.frame with fill = NA

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, data-binding, fillna

I have a vector of length 3 (`my_vector`).

I want to bind this vector to an existing data.frame (`my_df`) as a new column.

However, the data.frame has 4 rows. Thus, in the 4th row, the new column value (or `my_df[4,3]`) should be `NA`.

How can I achieve this?

When I do `my_df$new_column <- my_vector`, I get the following error message:
**replacement has 3 rows, data has 4**

---

Here is `my_df` (comprising 4 rows):

```
> dput(my_df)

structure(list(
      person = c("Oleg", "Yurii", "Igor", "Mikhail"),
      role = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), class = "factor", .Label = c("EDITOR-IN-CHIEF", "DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF", "Coordinating Editor"))),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -4L)
)
```

And `my_vector` (of length 3):

```
> dput(my_vector)

c("Lomonosov University", "Russian Academy of Sciences", "Institute of Acoustics, Moscow, Russia")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/7962267/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a `NA` column and then assign the 'my_vector' based on the length of the vector.  Here `seq_along(my_vector)` return `1:3`, thus the first 3 elements are replaced with 'my_vector' values

```
my_df$new_column <- NA_character_
my_df$new_column[seq_along(my_vector)] <- my_vector
```

---

Or this can be done in a single step if we pad `NA` at the end by making use of `length<-`

```
my_df$new_column <-  `length<-`(my_vector, nrow(my_df))
```

-output

```
my_df
#   person                    role                             new_column
#1    Oleg         EDITOR-IN-CHIEF                   Lomonosov University
#2   Yurii DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF            Russian Academy of Sciences
#3    Igor DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF Institute of Acoustics, Moscow, Russia
#4 Mikhail     Coordinating Editor                                   <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could subset the values from `my_vector` which has same length as `my_df`.

```
my_df$new_column <- my_vector[seq_len(nrow(my_df))]
my_df

#   person                    role                             new_column
#1    Oleg         EDITOR-IN-CHIEF                   Lomonosov University
#2   Yurii DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF            Russian Academy of Sciences
#3    Igor DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF Institute of Acoustics, Moscow, Russia
#4 Mikhail     Coordinating Editor                                   <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(my_df)[, new := NA][, new := replace(new, seq_along(my_vector), my_vector)]
```

gives

```
> my_df
    person                    role                                    new
1:    Oleg         EDITOR-IN-CHIEF                   Lomonosov University
2:   Yurii DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF            Russian Academy of Sciences
3:    Igor DEPUTY EDITORS-IN-CHIEF Institute of Acoustics, Moscow, Russia
4: Mikhail     Coordinating Editor                                   <NA>
```