# Transform a splitted data.frame in a new data. frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
>    Element1     Element2        Value           Index   
>          a         cf            0.14             1           
>          a         ng            0.25             1           
>          a         ck            0.12             1         
>          a         rt            0.59             1      
>          a         pl            0.05             1          
>          b         gh            0.02             2          
>          b         er            0.91             2
>          b         jk            0.87             2
>          c         qw            0.23             3
>          c         po            0.15             3
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>    Element_a1     Element_a2    Value_a       Element_b1   Element_b2  Value_b
>          a         cf            0.14             b            gh       0.02      
>          a         ng            0.25             b            er       0.91   
>          a         ck            0.12             b            jk       0.87
>          a         rt            0.59             NA           NA       NA
>          a         pl            0.05             NA           NA       NA
> ```

and so on...

I applied "split"  function to split the initial data.frame according to  "Index" column but I cannot transform the splitted data.frame (that is a list of data.frames) in a single `data.frame` as desired since the length of the single data.frames is not equal. I tried to apply (from ply package)

> x = do.call(rbind.fill, spl)

as from another post, but a data.frame like the initial one is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
nRow <-  max(table(dat$Element1))          # maximum number of rows in a group
spl2 <- by(dat, dat$Element1, FUN = function(x) {           
  if (nRow > nrow(x)) {                    # insufficient number of rows?
    subdat <- dat[seq_len(nRow - nrow(x)), ]  # create a data frame
    subdat[ , ] <- NA                      # fill it with NAs
    return(rbind(x, subdat))}       # bind it to the subset and return the result
  return(x)                                # return the subset as it is
})
result <- do.call(cbind, spl2)             # bind all subsets together
```

Comment: +1! I would do it like this..Maybe you can replace your split - lapply by a `by` somethin like ..`` by(dat,dat$Element1,..`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `split` and then `cbind` them together, post-padding. I borrow the `cbindPad` function from [combining two data frames of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184/combining-two-data-frames-of-different-lengths):

```
cbindPad <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args,nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(NA,mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      return(rbind(x,padTemp))
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
  return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}

## assume your data is in a data.frame called dat
dat_split <- split(dat, dat$Element1)
out <- do.call( cbindPad, dat_split )
```

Comment: Hi CauchyDistributedRV! Thanks a lot! It works very well. I would never be able to write such a complex function. Thanks a lot!