# Split dataframe at specifi row and arrange columns into "sections" in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a solution to split dataframes into smaller parts with specified length and then rearrange those parts into a new dataframe. The goal is to fit more data on a single page when printing narrow tables. For example this:

```html
index   v1
1   a
2   a
3   d
4   f
5   f
6   g
7   a
8   a
9   x
10  d
11  d
12  x
13  e
14  a
15  a
16  d
17  c
18  f
19  e
20  e
21  c
```

into this:

```html
index   v1  index   v1
1   a   7   a
2   a   8   a
3   d   9   x
4   f   10  d
5   f   11  d
6   g   12  x
13  e   19  e
14  a   20  e
15  a   21  c
16  d       
17  c       
18  f
```

In this example we split after every 6th row and arrange into two column sections (if we had a page that could fit 6 rows only). It would be nice to have split points and column section counts as variables. And how to reverse the process to make a regular table again for data analysis after extra data has been entered in Excel for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sinmpy do

```
after <- 6
cols <- 2
f <- ((seq(nrow(df)) - 1) %/% after) %% cols
d <- reshape(cbind(df, time = f, id = ave(f, f, FUN=seq)), dir="wide")

d[-1]

   index.0 v1.0 index.1 v1.1
1        1    a       7    a
2        2    a       8    a
3        3    d       9    x
4        4    f      10    d
5        5    f      11    d
6        6    g      12    x
13      13    e      19    e
14      14    a      20    e
15      15    a      21    c
16      16    d      NA <NA>
17      17    c      NA <NA>
18      18    f      NA <NA>
```

The reverse operation will be:

```
 reshape(d)[-(1:2)]
```

Comment: Works as needed. Renaming with repeated original names was easy. Would you be so kind and add the reverse operation as-well? To transform the result back to original.

Comment: @user2021713 Have added the reverse operation

Comment: reshape(d)[-(1:2)] gives me an error: Error in match.arg(direction, c("wide", "long")) : 
  argument "direction" is missing, with no default. Simply adding dir="long" is not enough.

Comment: @user2021713 do nit change d. Let d be exactly as it is. What you probably have to do is to assign d to another variable eg, e then change e as you qant, as long as you do not change d

Comment: well the reshape() function from stats package has a direction argument with no default value. So getting this error makes sense. I have not changed object d.

Comment: @user2021713 yes it has the direction and other parameters, although you can directly reshape an object that was previously reshaped since the direction is stored as an attribute in the object. When i mean change the object is by changing any of its attributes including names. You should not even change the names for example run `d<-reshape...` as line of code as shown in my code above and immediately after that run `reshape(d)` it should transform it

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining. Unfortunately this method is not useful for me as I need to modify a dataframe that was created without the reshape function directly before. It should work with any dataframe that has this structure. What attributes I need to add to make it work?

Comment: @user2021713 You could add the time variable and the direction = "long"

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty...

The `cbindPad` function (to fill incomplete columns) comes from [combining two data frames of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184)

```
library(tidyverse)

cbindPad <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args,nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      if (ncol(x)==0) {
        return(padTemp)
      } else {
        return(rbind(x,padTemp))
      }
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
  return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}


df <- tribble(
~index, ~ v1,
1,   "a",
2,   "a",
3,   "d",
4,   "f",
5,   "f",
6,   "g",
7,   "a",
8,   "a",
9,   "x",
10,  "d",
11,  "d",
12,  "x",
13,  "e",
14,  "a",
15,  "a",
16,  "d",
17,  "c",
18,  "f",
19,  "e",
20,  "e",
21,  "c") 

df %>% 
  group_split(ceiling(index / 6), .keep = FALSE) %>% 
  invoke(cbindPad, .)
```

We get :

```
index v1 index v1 index v1 index   v1
1     1  a     7  a    13  e    19    e
2     2  a     8  a    14  a    20    e
3     3  d     9  x    15  a    21    c
4     4  f    10  d    16  d    NA <NA>
5     5  f    11  d    17  c    NA <NA>
6     6  g    12  x    18  f    NA <NA>
```

Comment: This result is 4-wide on one "page". How to modify to get 2-wide or other widths?

Comment: change 6 : use 12. Depending of your objective, manipulating datframe like this is maybe not optimal ; consider looking at knitr::kable or DT::datatable for displaying