# Is there a way to split a long flextable into 2 side-by-side tables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown, flextable

I'm trying to split a (grouped) flextable into 2 side-by-side tables so that it will fit on one page.

Here is some data that is close enough to what I'm working with:

```r
# data ----

# data
data <- ggplot2::economics_long |>
    dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(date)) |>
    dplyr::select(variable, year) |>
    dplyr::arrange(year) |>
    data.table::as.data.table()

# n by year
year_n <- data[, .(n_year = .N), by = year]

# n by var, year
data <- data[, .N, by = .(variable, year)]

# merge together
data <- data.table::merge.data.table(
    data, year_n,
    by = "year"
)

# add percent
data[, percent := N / n_year]
```

Normally, I would use `flextable::as_grouped_data()`:

```r
# normal table
data |>
    flextable::as_grouped_data(
        groups = "year"
    ) |>
    flextable::as_flextable()
```

This results in a (very) long table.

[image]

The thought would be to split this into 2 side-by-side tables so it can cleanly fit on one page. My attempt at this is below.

I first get the row index by group and an overall index to see where to ideally split the table in two (such that each grouped table fits cleanly in one column).

```r
# get rows by group
data[, r := seq_len(.N), by = year]

# add overall index
data[, i := .I]

# find apx half split
n <- nrow(data) / 2
data[, h := abs(i - n)]
split <- data[r == 1][h == min(h)]$i

# remove unused
rm <- c("r", "i", "h")
data <- data[, (rm) := NULL]
```

I then split the data into 2 tables at that "optimal" index.

```r
# split into 2 tables
tab_1 <- data[seq_len(.N) < split] |>
    flextable::as_grouped_data(groups = "year")
tab_2 <- data[seq_len(.N) >= split] |>
    flextable::as_grouped_data(groups = "year")
```

From here, the thought would be to `cbind()` them back together into one data.frame. However, this results in:

```r
> cbind(tab_1, tab_2)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 144, 150
```

Luckily, thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184/combining-two-data-frames-of-different-lengths), I can `cbind` two data.frames of differing lengths which I would generally never do.

```r
cbind_bad <- function(...) {
    args <- list(...)
    n <- sapply(args, nrow)
    mx <- max(n)
    pad <- function(x, mx) {
        if (nrow(x) < mx) {
            nms <- colnames(x)
            pad_temp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
            colnames(pad_temp) <- nms
            if (ncol(x) == 0) {
                return(pad_temp)
            } else {
                return(rbind(x, pad_temp))
            }
        } else {
            return(x)
        }
    }
    rs <- lapply(args, pad, mx)
    return(do.call(cbind, rs))
}

# cbind w/ na's
combined <- cbind_bad(tab_1, tab_2)
```

From here, I rename the columns so I don't get this error:

```r
> flextable::as_flextable(combined)
Error in flextable(x, col_keys = colkeys) :
  duplicated col_keys: year, variable, N, n_year, percent
```

I also add a "space" column to use with `flextable::empty_blanks()` to add a space between the two tables.

```r
# get ncol
names <- paste0("c", seq_len(ncol(combined)))
keys <- c(
    paste0("c", seq_len(ncol(data))),
    "space",
    paste0("c", seq_len(ncol(data)) + ncol(data))
)

# rename so no duplicated column keys
combined <- combined |>
    data.table::as.data.table() |>
    data.table::setnames(names)
```

I then create a named list of the original column names to use with `flextable::set_header_labels()`. I also get the i, j index of the grouped variable to use with `flextable::bold()`.

```r
# create column names to use as header labs
rname <- colnames(data)
rname[1] <- ""
header_labs <- rep(rname, 2) |> as.list()
names(header_labs) <- names

# get i, j for bolding
i_1 <- "c1"
i_2 <- paste0("c", 1 + ncol(data))
j_2 <- 2 + ncol(data)
```

Finally, after all of this, I get pretty much what I'm after:

```r
# flextable
combined |>
    flextable::flextable(col_keys = keys) |>
    flextable::set_header_labels(
        values = header_labs
    ) |>
    flextable::empty_blanks(width = 1) |>
    flextable::bold(i = ~ !is.na(combined[, get(i_1)]), j = 1) |>
    flextable::bold(i = ~ !is.na(combined[, get(i_2)]), j = j_2) |>
    flextable::bold(bold = TRUE, part = "header")
```

[image]

Is there a better way to achieve this or something I'm missing? I thought about trying to use `flextable::tabulate()` but it seemed equally as complicated. Thank you!